# How to convert multiple CSV file to Multiple HTML table using AJAX and Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, csv

I have a code which will show an HTML table generated from a csv file on button click . but i want multiple csv file to convert to multiple HTML table on a single button click . Is it possible ?

So here is my script .

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 $('#Load-Data').click(function(){
  $.ajax({
   url:"OutputNew.csv",
   dataType:"text",
   success:function(data){
    var employee_data = data.split(/\r?\n|\r/);
    var table_data = '<div class="dropdown"><button class="dropbtn">Download</button><div class="dropdown-content"><a href="javascript:createPDF()">Download PDF</a><a href="javascript:downloadInnerHtml()" id="downloadLink">Download HTML</a><a href="javascript:exportTableToExcel()">Download Excel</a></div></div><input type="text" id="myInput" onkeyup="myFunction()" placeholder="Search for names.."><div id="VMTable"><div id="content"><table id="myTable" class="table table-striped""><thead>';
    
    for(var count = 0; count<employee_data.length; count++) {
     var cell_data = employee_data[count].split(',');
     table_data += '<tr>';
     for(var cell_count=0; cell_count<cell_data.length; cell_count++){
      if(count === 0){
       table_data += '<th id="headers" style="position=sticky">'+cell_data[cell_count]+'</th>';
      }else{
          if(cell_data[cell_count] .includes("Not Matching")){
                var ret = cell_data[cell_count].replace('Not Matching','');
                if (ret == ""){
                    table_data += '<td>'+ret+'</td>'
                }else{
                  table_data += '<td data-color="green"><span>'+ret+'</span></td>';
                }
          }else if(cell_data[cell_count] .includes("Matching")){
                var ret = cell_data[cell_count].replace('Matching','');
                if (ret == ""){
                  table_data += '<td>'+ret+'</td>';
                }else if(ret == " "){
                  table_data += '<td>'+ret+'</td>';
                }else{
                  table_data += '<td data-color="green"><span class="badge-complete" style="color:Green">'+ret+'</span></td>';
                }
          }else{
              table_data += '<td>'+cell_data[cell_count]+'</td>';
          }
      }
     }
     table_data += '</tr>';
    }
    table_data += '</table></div><iframe id="txtArea1" style="display:none"></iframe>';
    
    $('#employee_table').html(table_data);
   }
  });   
 }); 
});
```

and here is HTML button

```
<button type="button" name="Load-Data" id="Load-Data" class="btn btn-info">Generate Report</button>
```

Comment: what do you mean by "multiple csv file to convert to multiple HTML table"? Do you want to have the same functionality, just multiple times? why don't you enclose the code you have into a function and run it for however many times you need it?

Comment: i tried that but i want all the csv file in same page  @Magnus

Comment: are all files have same no of column or same column?

Comment: you creating lot of other things like button and dropdows. Do you want to create them for each CSV? What is table-data and #employee_table? Are we just putting table-data in side empty #employee table, so putting those buttons and drop-downs inside empty table tag???????

Comment: OK got my question answers from here: https://www.webslesson.info/2017/04/csv-file-to-html-table-using-ajax-jquery.html

Answer (score 1):

Check out this snippet:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>CSV Files to HTML Tables</title>
    <!-- JQuery -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>   
    <script>
        //add your files to csv_files array
        var csv_files=['username.csv', 'username-password-recovery-code.csv']
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $('#btn_load').click(function(){
                for(var i=0; i<csv_files.length; i++)
                    $.ajax({
                        url: csv_files[i],
                        dataType:'text',
                        success:function(data){
                            var rows = data.split(/\r?\n|\r/);
                            var table = '<table border="1">';
                            //row - iteration

                            //print table header
                            var headings = rows[0].split(";")
                            table += '<thead><tr>';
                            for(var j=0; j<headings.length; j++)
                                table += '<th>' + headings[j] + '</th>';
                            table += '</tr></thead>';

                            //print table body
                            table += '<tbody>';
                            for(var j=1; j<rows.length; j++){
                                var data_cell = rows[j].split(";")
                                table += '<tr>';
                                for(var k=0; k<headings.length; k++)
                                    table += '<td>' + data_cell[k] + '</td>';
                                table += '</tr>';
                            }
                            table += '</tbody>';

                            //closing table, add line break, appending result to div
                            table += '</table><br>';
                            $('#div_results').append(table);
                        }
                    });   
            }); 
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="div_results" style="border: 5px outset grey; padding: 10px;">
        <h2>--- Results ---</h2>
    </div>
    <button id="btn_load">Get External Content</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Because you haven't answered my questions I am presenting you a generalized solution. You can use this code to genereate HTML Tables for any no of CSVs having any no. of columns and rows. I have added `<thead>` and `<tbody>` tags for your ease. If you not wana use than you can remove them and do any further style specific alterations.